# Difference between Mozilla's new repository and ppa

Tags: firefox, ppa

Mozilla [introduced new package repositories](https://blog.nightly.mozilla.org/2023/10/30/introducing-mozillas-firefox-nightly-deb-packages-for-debian-based-linux-distributions/) for (nightly) deb packages. Apart from that [a ppa already exists](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) for a long time.

In the blog post's comments they already write that it should be introduced for stable releases as well. Does anyone has an idea what the difference between the ppa and the stable releases in the new repository could be and why they introduce a separate repo?

So, in the future: Should I use the new deb repositoy or the ppa? Or does it not make any difference?

Comment: you are asking for opinions...  use the one that works for you :P

Comment: Are you planning on using nightly packages? If not, what's the point on asking this? If so, then does it really make a difference? Let them get to stable first before worrying about "should I use this or that"

Comment: It would be better ask Mozilla about Mozilla's decisions and Mozilla's actions. As to which one you "should" use...Mozilla already answered that. Are you hoping for a different answer here?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Probably you're right and it does not really make a difference in the end and Mozilla has to answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that the new PPA is for nightly builds, with the sole purpose of facilitating testing of bleeding edge versions.

The PPA that already exists contains Firefox ESR and, since a few years, also stable regular releases.

So I think your choice is clear. Unless you want to contribute to Firefox by testing development versions, you should stick to the "[Firefox ESR and Thunderbird stable builds](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)" PPA.